# Custom Page in Web8 not working (C#)

Tags: web8, custom-page

I'm trying to create a custom page in web 8, to do it I'm following these steps:

1. Create a Custom Page from Tridion
2. Create an .aspx file in the File System (under WebUI/MyFolder)
3. Add the following simple code

   ```
   <%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentManager"%>
   <%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement"%>

   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"%>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html >
       <head id="head">
       </head>
       <body class="itemview">
           <div id="StackElement" class="stack horizontal fixed">
               <% Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component c = Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject("tcm:111-11111"); %>
           </div>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

But I get "**The type or namespace name 'Component' does not exist in the namespace 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**"

Any idea what might be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the Tridion Content Manager dlls in the bin directory of your custom page's virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the custom page you create in Tridion is just a link, so I created a complete new solution in Visual Studio using WebApi and once it worked locally I uploaded to the server and create a Custom Page (a link) to that new solution (which I moved to the server as published code).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below mention assembly reference. i hope it will work.!!!! please try here sample [example](http://www.curlette.com/?cat=20)

```
Tridion.ContentManager;
Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
Tridion.ContentManager.contentmanagement.Component
```

Comment: Same happens...

Comment: Creating custom page using core services?

Comment: Didn't try it, but the problem here is why Component is not being found... To use core services, I'll need more time to try it. Thx.